# How to make all stderr also go to stdout in Ruby CGI script

Tags: ruby, cgi, stdout, stderr

How to make all stderr goes to stdout?

The case is, I'm writing a simple Ruby CGI script, when in development mode, I want to make all gems I used when giving an error, it shows on stdout (browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect stderr to stdout from inside a Ruby script you can use the [`IO#reopen`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-i-to_io) method:

```
# script.rb
$stderr.reopen($stdout)
fail 'error' # Messages from execeptions are usually printed on stderr
```

If you run the script in the shell, redirecting stderr to `/dev/null`, you can see that the exception message is printed on stdout:

```
$ ruby script.rb 2> /dev/null
foo.rb:2:in `<main>': foo (RuntimeError)
```

**Edit**: That said you probably will have to find a more appropriate solution to print error messages on your browser, for example you will need to encode HTML entities in error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Add this as part of script.

2> stands for STDERR. &1 is a reference to STDOUT.

```
2>&1
```

Example:

```
script.rb > log.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: How to put those redirection symbol when I'm using uWSGI web server, I'm not running the ruby script on the Shell, but via web server (since it's CGI script, not a normal shell script)